# Pandas howto save index.to_period("Q") to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I would like save this format on excel file**

[image]

I use the following code to save.

```
df.index = Q_df.index.to_period("Q")
df.to_excel(path, sheet_name = 'Data')
writer.save()
```

Once saved, but I have this format.

[image]
Please help me find a solution.

Comment: try `df.index = Q_df.index.to_period("Q").astype(str)`